How to deploy one main Powershell script with an additional folder of dynamically loadable scripts to powershell gallery?
Consider one main script foo.ps1 that is capable to read from a subfolder library containing other scripts being like plugins (no importing, those are scripts, not modules).
I would like to publish this into powershell gallery with the intend to have the main script in the search path after installation and didn't found right documentation on this.
Additionally using ChatGPT I found a proposed path to define a nuget Package to deploy and also a proposed path deploying it as a module. Using the proposed module solution doesn't look reasonable since I do not have modules and using the nuget package I can create a package but get constantly warnings about all scripts that should be placed into a tools folder.
Could somebody please given me some hints on how to do this right?

Powershell uses the environmental variable PSMODULEPATH to locate PS cmdlets.  You need to install into an existing ps path or modify the PSMODULEPATH for the cmdlets to be located.

That ist true but is not related to my question. Deployment to powershell gallery is the topic
